# CRUD Operation in JSONStore using MobileFirst Platform 7.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I'm new to MFP and I'm trying to perform a basic CRUD operation. Nothing is happening after the following code is executed. I will highly appreciate if i can get some help. Thank you.

**main.js**

```
function wlCommonInit () {

var collections = {
          people : {
            searchFields: {name: 'string', age: 'integer'}
          }
        };

        WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(function (collections) {
          // handle success - collection.people (people's collection)
        }).fail(function (error) {
            alert("alert" + error);
          // handle failure
        });


        var collectionName = 'people';
        var options = {};

        var data = {name: 'yoel', age: 23};

        WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(data, options).then(function () {
         // handle success
        }).fail(function (error) {
         // handle failure
        });




        // to display results using query yoel
        var query = {name: 'yoel'};

        var collectionName = 'people';

        var options = {
          exact: false, //default
          limit: 10 // returns a maximum of 10 documents, default: return every document

        };

        WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).find(query, options).then(function (results) {
          // handle success - results (array of documents found)
        }).fail(function (error) {
          // handle failure
        });         
}//end wlCommonInit
```

Comment: Any errors message from the logs?

Answer (score 1):

JSONStore is asynchronous. With the code you wrote you cannot be sure of the order it is run.

The JavaScript code is most likely calling one of your `add()` or `find()` before your `init()` happens.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not writing the code within `wlCommonInit` because JSONStore may not be loaded yet. You could try tying it to a event like a button press or just put it into a function then call it in the console. Also, like @Chevy Hungerford has said, JSONStore is asynchronous so utilize the promises by chaining.

```
var collections = {
      people : {
        searchFields: {name: 'string', age: 'integer'}
      }
    };
// to display results using query yoel
var query = {name: 'yoel'};

var options = {
      exact: false, //default
      limit: 10 // returns a maximum of 10 documents, default: return every document

    };

var collectionName = 'people';
var data = [{name: 'yoel', age: 23}]; //best if the data is an array

    WL.JSONStore.init(collections).then(function (collections) {
      // handle success - collection.people (people's collection)
          return WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).add(data);
    })
    .then(function (res){
           return WL.JSONStore.get(collectionName).find(query, options)
    })
    .then(function (res){
       //handle success - getting data
    })
    .fail(function (error) {
        alert("alert" + error);
      // handle failure
    });
```